# Save to database sequentially with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to write a back-end in NodeJS for a newsreader app. The idea is to check a number of RSS feeds every few minutes, save new items to a database, and emit an event to connected users when a new item is added to the database.

I am having trouble writing a module which saves to the database. The desired behaviour is as follows:

1. Take the parsed RSS feeds, which are ordered in an array from newest to oldest, as input
2. For each item, starting with the newest, attempt to save it in the database
3. If the save was successful, log 'Save successful' to the console and attempt the next item
4. If the save fails, because the item already exists in the database, stop running the module.

The database model is already configured so the database does reject it when I try to save an item which already exists. However, the code below never logs the successful saves, and if I drop the database, it only saves the first document and then gives me a duplicate key error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
// Module

var { mongoose } = require('../db/mongoose');
var { Item } = require('../models/item');
var { scrape } = require('./scrape')
var { parse } = require('./parse')

var updateNewsDatabase = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Scraping now')
        scrape().then((rssFeeds) => {
            var output = parse(rssFeeds);
            saveEachNewsItem(output)
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log('Error:', e);
                    resolve()
                })
        })
    });
}

async function saveEachNewsItem(newsItems) {
    for (let item of newsItems) {
        console.log('Attempting to save document')
        var itemToSave = new Item(item);
        await itemToSave.save()
            .then((err, docs) => {
                if (docs) {
                    console.log('Saved document to database')
                }
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error(err)
                }
            });
    }
}

module.exports = { updateNewsDatabase }
```

Comment: If you need to insert in order so that the database works shows that its badly designed. If you need some kind of sorting you should create an index.

Comment: I don't need to do it that way, thought it would be a good solution since each fetch will result in none, one or at most two items added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code, you are throwing exception and it makes it stop the for loop.

```
await itemToSave.save()
        .then((err, docs) => {
            if (docs) {
                console.log('Saved document to database')
            }
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err)
            }
        });
```